# ASP.NET AJAX - updates in panel resend all page validation script

Tags: asp.net-ajax, telerik, telerik-grid

I am using a [RadGrid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx) from Telerik with Ajax enabled. Whenever an Ajax call happens, the page responds with 56 KB of JavaScript validators in addition to the new grid data (in addition to 40k of viewstate - argh). Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Is the 56KB of javascript not cached?

Comment: It sounds like this is performing like it is supposed to.

**Are you using an AJAX UpadatePanel?**

See, the thing about those UpdatePanels is that *everything* in them gets re-sent every time the page updates.

Comment: Viewstate off and option?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried binding it to a web service instead of doing standard server-side binding? See
"[ASP.NET Grid Demo - .NET 3.5 - .NET 3.5 Client-side Data Binding](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/clientbinding/defaultcs.aspx)".

Most of the Telerik controls, which I have experience with, get about a 10 times speedup when you switch to web services from server-side Ajax.